# Configuring Multiple store directories - Carrierwave s3 upload

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, carrierwave

I have application where we have posts to which we upload photos. I have implemented S3 uploading module using carrier-wave and fog integration which is successful. But when images are uploaded along with versions the original file also getting stored in the same directory.

Is there any way to configure a separate folder inside my bucket to store only original images and rest of the images separately.

I also searched and learned that operating with multiple buckets is not yet possible with carrier-wave.

Kindly please direct me on this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Nope! Is there a reason why you'd want to?

Comment: and keep in mind that directories on S3 are an illusion